# Android, как правильно организовать классы для Room?

Tags: android, android-room

Убиваюсь об проблему отношения "много к одному", прошу совета касательно того как правильно организовать простенькую бд.

У меня есть три таблички, назову их условно так:

`Автомобили` - `Группы автомобилей` - `Текста для автомобилей`

Изначально я всё сделал вроде как по уму:

`Автомобили` содержали в себе только то что описывает сам автомобиль:

`id`, `description`, `color`, `price`

`Группы автомобилей` содеражали в себе записи, которые хранили  несколько `id` автомобилей. То есть записи вида:

`id`, `cars_ids`, где `cars_ids` это несколько `id` автомобилей, строкой.

`Текста для автомобилей` - содержали в себе записи, которые хранили текста про конкретный автомобиль:

`id`, `car_id`,`car_history`, `car_damage`,...

Для таблиц были соответственно классы `Car`, `CarGroup` и `CarTexts`. Всё было хорошо, но видимо я был не дальновиден и возникла проблема когда передо мной встала задача извлечь из таблицы `Автомобили` все машины какой - то группы. То есть я делал SELECT в таблицу `Группы автомобилей`, получал массив чисел `cars_ids` и - что дальше? У меня было условно 20 чисел(id машин), и мне пришлось делать 20 SELECT в базу `Автомобили` чтобы для каждого `id` из группы достать свой автомобиль. По другому Room не умеет.

Тогда я сделал, как мне кажется не совсем правильную вещь. Я удалил `cars_id` из `Группы автомобилей`, и добавил поле `group` в таблицу `Aвтомобили`, чтобы каждый автомобиль хранил в себе группу в которой он состоит. Таблица `Группы автомобилей` стала не нужна и я её удалил. И снова всё было хорошо, пока мне не понадобилось достать несколько записей из `Текста для автомобили`, имея несколько `car_id`. То есть мне опять нужно делать несколько SELECT в `Текста для автомобилей`, чтобы сформировать массив данных. Я могу решить это, снова соединив `Автомобили` и `Текста для автомобилей`, но это уже ни в какие ворота вообще, мне нужна DB а не помойка.

Вопрос - что я делаю не так и как организовать БД? По тому что я гуглил, советуют именно мерджить таблицы. Нет уж, благодарю.

Comment: во первых вы не правильно выстроили структуру БД. Вы в группе хранили id автомобилей, которые относятся к группе. А теперь попробуйте просто оставить В группе, только id группы (на примере марки авто, id, name_mark). А у автомобилей добавить id, который указывает к какой группе автомобилей (Марки), он принадлежит

Comment: Вы можете в каждой таблице создать некий уникальный ключ, и связывать этим ключом конкретные места в разных таблицах. А выборку SELECT делать по этому ключу.